# How can I keep my ex-boss out of my life?

Tags: personal-problems

I started working with a small firm about an year ago. I loved my job until my boss started controlling everything I did. She was never satisfied with anything that I did and was constantly pointing out things I cannot call mistakes. She made sure I did not get to talk to other colleagues around the office and each time I did, would call out my name loudly or embarrass me in some way or another which kept the others at bay.
I could no longer stand this behaviour and decided to quit. After about 6-7 months of working under her I left stating that I was moving to a different city.
Now even after months of me leaving the organisation, she keeps texting me asking me to take up courses or take up a new job. I haven't let her know much about my life after I left the company but she makes sure she keeps on with her antics.

I'd like to know how I can get her to stop without saying it outright to her face and being rude.

Comment: IIRC, you can easily block a number with any modern phones. What exactly are the problems here? Is she harassing you? Is she bypassing the block by using throwaway numbers?

Comment: I‘m more curious about why she suggests you do things to better yourself...is there a possibility this woman has a crush on you...? It seems bizarre that this person appears to be invested in you getting better months later..although clearly it isn‘t appropriate and unwanted attention, whatever kind it may be...are the suggestions even remotely relevant? *Should* you be taking courses?

Comment: Any chance your boss is also your mother?

Comment: Why do you keep her up-to-date? If you left even your job because of her, you really should *leave*, entirely. Your life is not her business, or is it?

Answer (score 13):

Just block her. Don't engage in a dialogue over the reasons, it's not constructive and creates an opening.

This is one of the reasons people have separate numbers and email addresses for work and personal life.

Comment: +1 and if that's not enough (or matters escalate) then in most 1st world countries quick visit to police station and filling a report will put a stop to it.

Answer (score 8):

> Now even after months of me leaving the organisation, she keeps
> texting me asking me to take up courses or take up a new job.
>
> I'd like to know how I can get her to stop without saying it outright
> to her face and being rude.

This is an easy one: **stop responding to her texts**.

Once she realizes you aren't answering, she'll stop trying. And if she persists, just block her.

Comment: Note that she may start calling instead. So blocking the number too may be a good idea.

Answer (score 6):

> I'd like to know how I can get her to stop without saying it outright to her face and being rude.

Why?

In the circumstances it would be perfectly reasonable, some would say expected, to say that you have moved on and are no longer interested in courses or job offers.

If this does not work then your next most graceful option would be to block her.

Answer (score -1):

Confront and tell her you are not comfortable with all this. I guess you could block and avoid her but I doubt that mature person would act like this. Also it's possible that she   is pursuing romantic relationship with you, have you considered this perspective ?

Comment: Why is blocking a stalker not "mature"? If at all, I would consider it immature to continue responding to someone that does not leave you alone.